# Cannot print hdfs topology when using viewfs:/// as fs.defaultFS

Tags: hadoop

I am using Rack Awareness technology in HDFS, I can use the following command to get topology:

> hdfs dfsadmin -printTopology

Today, after setting up HDFS Federation and use viewfs instead of hdfs as defaultFS like this:

```
<!--                                                                                                                                              
  <property>                                                                                                                                      
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>                                                                                                                     
    <value>hdfs://namenode1:9000</value>                                                                                                          
  </property>                                                                                                                                     
-->
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>viewfs:///</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.viewfs.mounttable.default.link./ns1</name>
    <value>hdfs://namenode1:9000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.viewfs.mounttable.default.link./ns2</name>
    <value>hdfs://namenode2:9000</value>
  </property>
```

I got error message:

```
hduser@namenode1:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ hdfs dfsadmin -printTopology
printTopology: FileSystem viewfs:/ is not an HDFS file system
Usage: java DFSAdmin [-printTopology]
```

So my questions are:

1. Is it better using viewfs in federation than using hdfs?
2. Does viewfs support Rack Awareness & printTopology command?

I am new to HDFS cluster, hope could get advice from here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a new hadoop cilent ,and set the core-site.xml like this:
   property:fs.defaultFS  value:hdfs://your active namenode host:port
   not viewfs protocol
   then you can use hdfs client comment

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. Your answer has some serious formatting issues. Please reformat it. I have removed your e-mail address. Have a look at the formating help: http://serverfault.com/help/formatting